# Why is require.js ignoring config baseUrl and paths

Tags: url, path, requirejs

I am having a problem where almost-identical require.js config calls appear to work differently, in one case failing to set `baseUrl` and `path`.

**Folder structure**

```
 - /js
 - - app/
 - - libs/
 - - - hogan.js
 - - - backbone
 - - - - backbone.js
 - - - - etc.
 - - - boostrap
 - - - jquery
 - - - - jquery.js
 - - - - etc.
 - - - require
 - - - - require.js
 - - - - etc.
 - - templates/
 - - require.config.js
```

**Script tag**

`<script data-main="/resources/js/require.config" src="/resources/js/libs/require/require.js"></script>`

**Require configuration**

```
require.config(
    {
        baseUrl: "/resources/js/libs",
        shim: {
            "underscore": {
                exports: "_"
            },
            "backbone": {
                deps: [
                    "json2",
                    "underscore",
                    "jquery"
                ],
                exports: "Backbone"
            }
        },
        paths: {
            "app": "/resources/js/app",
            "backbone": "backbone/backbone",
            "jquery": "jquery/jquery",
            "templates": "/resources/js/templates",
            "templateEngine": "hogan"
        }
    }
);

require(
    [
        "app/router"
    ],
    function( AppRouter ){
        AppRouter.execute();
    } 
);
```

In both cases, a script tag gets appended that shows the full contents of require.config.js, starting with:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="require.config" src="/resources/js/require.config.js">`

**Definition in app/router**

```
define(
    [
        'backbone',
        'templateEngine'
    ],
// etc
);
```

However where the problem occurs, app/router is never loaded, only the following (no 404, nothing):

```
GET require.js 200 OK 180ms     
GET require.config.js 200 OK 69ms
```

If I enter `require(["app/router"]);` into the Firebug console I get the following:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /resources/js/backbone.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /resources/js/templateEngine.js"
```

When what I expect to see is:

- /resources/js/libs/backbone/backbone.js
- /resources/js/libs/hogan.js

**Solutions attempted**

- I have attempted to use various combinations of relative and absolute paths for `baseUrl` and `paths`.  For example `baseUrl: libs`, and `paths: { "app" : "../app" }`, etc.
- I tried `deps` and `callback` instead of using `require` below `config`.
- I have added the property `context`, matching `baseUrl`.
- I have moved *require.config.js* into the *libs* directory (editing `baseUrl` and `paths` as appropriate; still get the same issue of ignored config,  only it tries to load */resources/js/libs/backbone.js* instead, for example).

**Note**

This folder structure and config file does work on my localhost, where I remove */resources/* from the paths as shown above.  Instead all-relative paths (none starting with /) are used for `baseUrl` and `paths`.  But on the actual server that is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution was to not have any . (periods) in the configuration file's filename.  After renaming the file to require-config.js everything worked as expected. Other files are fine with dots in the name, just not the main configuration file.

Comment: I had the same issue. If you ever don't want to alter the filename, you can alias the module via the path hash in requirejs config.  e.g.  "require.config({paths: {myModule: "/path/to/my.weird.module"}})"

Comment: I don't think you can alias your config filename, though. This works if the config file itself isn't affected.